# Get the text from a TextView

Tags: android, textview

How can I get the text as String from a textview?

I tried:

```
myTextView.getText();
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get text from TextView, use `.getText()` and then convert it to string using `.toString()`

```
String s = myTextview.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged in SO.

Answer (score 5):

The correct way to get the text from a String is almost that! You simply forgot to use `toString()`

So, to get it as a string all you need to do is

```
myTextview.getText().toString();
```

this will give you the String you need (then just use it how you please).

The reason just getText() did not work was because it returns an Editable object, not a String.

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html):

> This is the interface for text whose content and markup can be changed
>   (as opposed to immutable text like Strings). If you make a
>   DynamicLayout of an Editable, the layout will be reflowed as the text
>   is changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
String mString =myTextView.getText() + " ";
```

get Text From the Textview from getText() Method and then Convert it to String ....

Comment: You should strive to explain your code snippets when answering questions.